# New to CUDA and Compute Visual Profiler

Tags: cuda, profiling

I am reading this book "Cuda by Example" and i am having difficulties starting a new project, writing, compiling, executing and profiling some code. I found this blug post:

http://blog.cuvilib.com/2010/10/28/profiling-cuda-applications-on-windows-with-nvidia-compute-visual-profiler/

but it uses an example from NVIDIA site. What is I want to start my own project from scratch? In the session settings window I don't know what to enter there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a new project and write CUDA code on your own, you should open Visual Studio, push "New" to make new project, and there, if you have CUDA Toolkit and Parallel NSight installed, you will see "Nvidia->CUDA" and choose whichever runtime version you want. [image]

If you don't have Visual Studio, then you can just write a code in any editor and compile it from cmd.exe/terminal by writing "nvcc name_of_your_file.cu"

NVIDIA Compute Visual Profiler is just a tool to make you understand the performance in your application and to help you to find out how to make your code run faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the NVidia documentation: 
http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-gpu-computing-documentation 
with a specific document "Getting Started Guide" that is very useful and explain all the first steps. 
Cuda by Example is a fantastic book to start, but I recommend you to read also the Programming Guide.

Ps: I have used Eclipse as Ide, but with a plugin.